# Return constant reference from non-const function return reference value

Tags: c++, reference, const-correctness

I have a class where getting a certain member by reference involves a logic, so I created a private getter function for it, which is working fine internally.

I would also want to provide public access to the same reference, but with a constant modifier. 
As the public function should not modify the state of the class, it is declared with the const keyword. 
However the internal logic, because it provides a reference to an internal member by design it should not be declared const.

How am I able to use the same logic for getting the reference, and provide a both const and non-const access point to it?

Is there a pattern I'm missing here?

Below I compiled a small example to demonstrate:

```cpp
class my_class{
public:

  const int& get_my_field() const{
    return get_my_field_ref(); //g++: error: error - passing 'const my_class' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  }

private:
    int field;

    int& get_my_field_ref(){ //g++: warning: note - in call to 'int& my_class::get_my_field_ref()'
      /* ..complex logic to get reference.. */
      return field;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why does `get_my_field_ref()` need to be non-`const`?

Comment: Because 'g++: error
error - binding reference of type 'int&' to 'const int' discards qualifiers' if it's const

Comment: I understand the error you're getting.   I specifically asked why the function `get_my_field_ref()` needs to be non-`const` - and you have not answered that.

Comment: oh, sure thank you for the patience! 
That interface is specifically used internally to modify the `field` on purpose.

Comment: The make `field` a `mutable` member.   That allows it to be changed in a `const` member function.

Comment: well if no const-casting-like mechanic is usable, I'd rather just remove the const modifier: ``const int& get_my_field() const{...} , so it would appear as non-const, even though it doesn't modify the state of the class.. what do you think about that?

Comment: That's the thing.  A member function marked `const` (after the function argument list) cannot call a function that is not marked `const` (at least, not without workarounds that typically introduce undefined behaviour).   The `const` tells the compiler that the function will not change the object.   The missing `const` tells the compiler that the function may change the object.

Comment: @Peter you were right, the original question had no correct answer, just workarounds. A design shift was needed. Because of this I would not delete this question, but answered it with the design changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking it through, the problem lies in the design mostly.

What the example program failed to mention was that the "complex logic" was to get an index inside an array. So with this information in mind, the logic to calculate the indices could be separated, and used in both const and non-const interfaces.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class my_class{
public:

  const int& get_my_field() const{
    return field[complex_logic_to_get_reference()];
  }

private:
    int field[5];

    int complex_logic_to_get_reference() const{
      int result_index = 0;
      /* Complex logic to get reference */
      return result_index;
    }

    int& get_my_field_ref(int index){
      return field[complex_logic_to_get_reference()];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

My apologies to @j6t and @Peter for leaving this information out at the time of posting the question, the concept really just clicked now.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Some people</strike> You can do it like this as long as you are aware of the caveats:

```
int& get_my_field_ref(){'
  /* ..complex logic to get reference.. */
  return field;
}
const int& get_my_field_ref() const {
  return const_cast<my_class&>(*this).get_my_field_ref();
}
```

Note though that a `const` member function more or less guarantees that it can be use without incurring data races (a.k.a. it is thread-safe). You should implement your `complex logic` to be thread-safe.

Also, make sure to never invoke your function on objects that have been defined `const`. (`const` references and pointers are OK as long as they trace back to a non-const object.)

Comment: Too bad for "some people" that doing such things introduces undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter True, but only if they use the function on `const` objects. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted this as the answer. However I've decided that it's safer to just remove the const modifier from the get_my_field member function.

Comment: @Peter: It's only UB if the non-const `get_my_field_ref` modifies the state of the object (and the object itself is declared `const`).